# What is standard way to handle Null dates in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, null

I have asp.net form with C#, where is I am taking user information to insert in the database as usual  by using Linq. well. Where as I am taking Date of birth also from the user, but if user skip to fill date text box from ui, then I am getting date like '01/01/0001' something like this, which certainly database security would not allow to store it.

So I need to check somewhere in my code that it is null or in this (above given) format. If it is null or in format '01/01/0001' then what exactly I have to do? I don't have any default 
value for dates.

So what is the standard way to handle if date is null (but not mandatory).Please guide me. So many times I found myself in trap while handling null for various types.

**Edited**
see what i did seems it working here. but i don't think so this is standard way:

```
DateTime? otxtDOB = new DateTime();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DOB))
                    {
                    if (Convert.ToDateTime(DOB) != DateTime.MinValue)
                        {
                        otxtDateOfPurchese = Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(DOB).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
                        }
                    else
                    {
                     otxtDOB = null;
                        }

                    }
```

Please confirm me is this right way ?

Comment: Simply i can say DateTime? dt = null;

Comment: no suppose I have used here DateTime not DateTime?

Comment: this is pretty old datetime just a joker '?' is added to make it nullable, that is to accept null values.

Comment: hello .... i could not get any answer here

Comment: ok bu then how to change that "jocker's" date format ? i want that format in dd-MMM-yyy form. where if i tried to do like this Datetime? dt= dateValue != null ?Covert.ToDateTime(dateValue.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") ): null; which is not wprking

Comment: See my updated answer. Might it help you.

Answer (score 13):

Making the date property `Nullable` (i.e. a "`DateTime?`") should allow it to actually be null if the user hasn't set it. (And provided your database column will allow nulls, it can be stored as null in the database)

Otherwise it's going to default to `DateTime.MinValue` which is what you're seeing here. And you'll have to explicity test for `DateTime.MinValue` when adding to the database.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime is a value type (like a number), so you can't assing a null value to it. Mane people use DateTime.MinValue or DateTime.MaxValue instead, but I prefer to use nullable types:

```
DateTime? nullableDate;
dateSample.Value = null;
```

Comment: but as i tried to assign null value to date time I am getting exception As: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DateTime' and '<null>' why should this?

Comment: see this line :             DateTime? dt = Convert.ToDateTime(DOB) != DateTime.MinValue ? Convert.ToDateTime(DOB) : null; is this right code or wrong?

Comment: I think the problem is in your conditional sentence. Try a conventional if-else conditional an check if any conversion to datetime? is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have the option of using `Nullable<DateTime>` (alias `DateTime?`). This makes you able to handle the date as null throughout your application.

However, personally I am not to found of nullables and would prefer this second path: You can use `DateTime.MinValue` (which is 01/01/0001) as a meaningful constant in your application and the check for DateTime.MinValue in your data access layer.

The database, if it is an SQL Server and the field is of type smalldatetime, would overflow and throw an exception if you tried to save `DateTime.MinValue`. Null however, may well be stored in the database for any type.

This is how you can parse your strings into nullable types:

```
private delegate bool TryParseDelegate<T>(string s, out T t);
private static T? TryParseNullable<T>(string s, TryParseDelegate<T> tryParse) where T : struct
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
       return null;
   T t;
   if(tryParse(s, out t))
      return t;
   return null;
}
```

with usage:

```
var nullableDateTime = TryParseNullable<DateTime>("01/01/0001", DateTime.TryParse);
```

Comment: but as i tried to assign null value to date time I am getting exception As: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DateTime' and '<null>' why should this? 
see this line : DateTime? dt = Convert.ToDateTime(DOB) != DateTime.MinValue ? Convert.ToDateTime(DOB) : null; is this right code or wrong?

Comment: As DateTime is a _value type_ it cannot be null. Therefore you cannot the `Convert.ToDateTime()` method and null together in a conditional expression. What is `DOB` in this case? A string?

Comment: yes,DOB is string . if i cannot do abouve explained thing then what is the standards for the same? any code reference

Answer (score 0):

you can do some thing like this C# have some features like nullable type you can make use of
this it will save you some piece of code it will be more robust too.

```
Public int InsertData(int? ouId)
{

chkValue = ouId.HasValue ? ouId.Value : 0;
}
```

Comment: I think my question about DateTime. I am aware of nullable as all are given me reply. but i am not sure about how can i change date format ?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
DateTime dt; 
if(DateTime.TryParse(DatetImeValue.Tostring(),dt))   // datetimevalue is your db value
{
     datetimeproperty = dt;   // in your class declare it as DateTime? datetimeproperty 
}
else
{
    datetimeproperty = null;
}
```

While displaying check for null, if its null set it empty.

**[Update]**

**Do one thing, Keep the property nullable. In your database. Set field to allow null and in the parameter user @DateTimeParam = null.**

**OR A QUICK WORKAROUND MAKE THE DATABASE FIELD AND PARAMETER VARCHAR INSTEAD OF DATETIME,  IN PARAMETER PASS DATETIMEVALUE.TOSHORTDATESTRING() AND ALSO CHECK IF USER SKIPS 
PUT STRING.EMPTY IN PARAMETER. IN THIS MANNER IT WILL BE EASY TO YOU TO DISPLAY DATE AND TIME. YOU NEED NOT CAST OR WIPE OFF THE TIME PART IF YOU DO NOT NEED IT**

Answer (score 0):

```
obj.BirthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBirthDate.Text.ToString()) ? System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value : Convert.ToDateTime(txtBirthDate.Text.ToString()));
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this while passing to database.

```
object datetimeObj = null;
if (datetimefromUI == DateTime.MinValue) // This is put in the DateTime object by default
    datetimeObj = DBNull.Value;
else
    datetimeObj = datetimefromUI;

// Post datetimeObj to parameter in database...
```

Comment: C# has nullables, they should be used instead.